# how can i add user avatar to admin menu

Tags: media

What function do I need to use for adding the image in the admin menu?

> [image]

Comment: To the best of my knowledge there isn't an existing function for that, you'll probably need to write your own

Answer (score 1):

Above menu is rendered from toolbar.tpl.php inside toolbar module.

All you need to is override above toolbar.tpl.php by copying it to your themes folder and modify code to add image.

```
<?php

/**
 * @file
 * Default template for admin toolbar.
 *
 * Available variables:
 * - $classes: String of classes that can be used to style contextually through
 *   CSS. It can be manipulated through the variable $classes_array from
 *   preprocess functions. The default value has the following:
 *   - toolbar: The current template type, i.e., "theming hook".
 * - $toolbar['toolbar_user']: User account / logout links.
 * - $toolbar['toolbar_menu']: Top level management menu links.
 * - $toolbar['toolbar_drawer']: A place for extended toolbar content.
 *
 * Other variables:
 * - $classes_array: Array of html class attribute values. It is flattened
 *   into a string within the variable $classes.
 *
 * @see template_preprocess()
 * @see template_preprocess_toolbar()
 *
 * @ingroup themeable
 */
?>
<div id="toolbar" class="<?php print $classes; ?> clearfix">
  <div class="toolbar-menu clearfix">
    <?php print render($toolbar['toolbar_home']); ?>
    <?php print render($toolbar['toolbar_user']); ?>
    <?php print render($toolbar['toolbar_menu']); ?>
    <?php

    $variables = array(
      'path' => 'path/to/img.jpg',
      'alt' => 'Test alt',
      'title' => 'Test title',
      'width' => '5px',
      'height' => '5px',
      'attributes' => array('class' => 'some-img', 'id' => 'my-img'),
      );
      print theme_image($variables)?>
    <?php if ($toolbar['toolbar_drawer']):?>
      <?php print render($toolbar['toolbar_toggle']); ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
  </div>

  <div class="<?php echo $toolbar['toolbar_drawer_classes']; ?>">
    <?php print render($toolbar['toolbar_drawer']); ?>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi But how can i know the path? i dont have an image ... sorry for asking to many question in new with drupal :)

Comment: https://drupal.org/node/22271 -- Enabling User Pictures http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6899813/how-to-display-user-avatar-in-drupal-7 -- Display User Avatar

Comment: that shows mt anonymos picture -[code]
    <?php

    $variables = array(
      'path' => 'path/to/img.jpg',
      'alt' => 'Test alt',
      'title' => 'Test title',
      'width' => '5px',
      'height' => '5px',
      'attributes' => array('class' => 'some-img', 'id' => 'my-img'),
      );
$user_item = user_load_by_name($username); // or user_load( $user->uid )
print theme('user_picture', array('account' =>$user_item));
      print theme_image($variables)

?>
[/code]